# Reconstruct Create-Table-statement from Select-Statements

Tags: sql, select, create-table

### Question

**Are there any tools or APIs that can do the following *conversion/transformation*?**

**Input:** A Select-statement of arbitrary complexity (e.g can contain multiple joins, unions etc. pp.) for example `SELECT x, y, z FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.p = B.p LEFT JOIN C on B.q = C.q`

**Output:** A Create-statement that creates all neccessary tables.

---

### Background:

I have 50+ Select-statements for which I need to generate tables. This is a somehow tedious task.

### Additional Questions

I think it is possible to automate. Correct me if I am wrong with this assumption and provide a explanation in case it is not possible to automate. I know the Select-statements can lack information, that the real database would have.

Comment: Think about how would would do it logically, then figure out how to build a SQL parser that replicates that logic (accounting for functions, aggregations, aliases, etc.) It's probably possible, but outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: This can't be done. How to find columns not selected? How do decide which table column x belongs to? How to decide data types, and all kind of constraints?

Comment: @jarlh 1.) If a column is not selected the Create-statement would not contain that column (lack of information as I said). 2.) In above example-statement the column `x` clearly belongs to table `A`. 3.) In the Select-statement above due to lack of information the Create-statements do not consider data types or constraints and create everything as varchar (for example).

Comment: How can you say "In above example-statement the column x clearly belongs to table A"? Columns can be in any order.

Comment: @DStanley Of course it is outside the forum. The question is: Are there API's for this task in Java or any other language?

Comment: @jarlh In this case the API can assume that `x` belongs to `A`, because `A` is the only referenced table in the FROM-clause. Clear enough?

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with this is that you do not have the relevant information in order to create the tables. You would have to make a  lot of assumptions

You are missing the following info:

- Datatypes `CHAR(10), INT, BIT`
- Constraints `NOT NULL, DEFAULT()`
- Index information

...and that is just the start, not every query will list all fields and you'll probably find that you've missed stuff the next time a table is referenced - what do you do then??

The only way this could be done is if you have very script coding standards in place.
For example:

- All columns called `Modified` are of type `DATETIME NOT NULL`
- All primary keys take the name of the table plus ID, eg. `TablenameID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` (you can use also use the `CONSTRAINT` option to create the key with a specific name)

... you get the idea.

I would just bite the bullet and get on with it manually.

### Edit

The real question here is why are you doing it this way? Surely the queries have been created against an existing database?

Is it the case that you are migrating from one RDBMS to another?

Comment: Actually, I am extending an Application which does a proof of concept by querying a DB and creating Excel-sheets. There is some business logic involved through these SQL statements.